# How to get the top group from sqlite query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I am using sqlite chinook database, and came across this scenario:
the db represents a music store with `invoices` tables linked to `customers`.

`Invoices` table has a `total` column which I can aggregate it using `sum()` grouping by the `country` from `customers` table.

```
SELECT 
    c.country,
    sum(i.total) totalspent,
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname

FROM 
    invoices i
    left join customers c on c.customerid= i.customerid

group by
    c.country,
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname

order by 2 desc
```

This will output something like this:

```
.---------------------------------------------.
| Country  | totalspent | firstname | lastname |
|----------------------------------------------|
| Czech R. | 49.62      |  Helena   |  Holy    |
| USA      | 47.62      |  Richard  | Cunning  |
| Chile    | 46.62      |  Luis     | Rojas    |
| Hungary  | 45.62      |  Ladislav | Kovac    |
| Ireland  | 45.62      |  Hugh     | O'Reilly |
| USA      | 43.62      |  Julia    | Barnett  |
...
...
```

You will notice that the table is sorted by `totalSpent` descending. This will cause people from the same country appear in different order due to how much they spent.

How can I only get the top 1 row per each country?
I tried to `select max()` of `total` grouped by each country but that did not work.

Here is what I attempted:

```
select 
  ...
  ...
where
    sum(i.total) in (select max(sm) 
                     from ( select 
                                  sum(ii.total) sm 
                             from 
                                  invoices ii left join customers cc 
                                     on cc.customerid = ii.customerid 
                             where cc.country = c.country ))


 ...
 group by
    ...
```

But that also did not work.

There must be a more straight forward way to select only the top country from the result rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE:

```
with ic as (
      select c.country, sum(i.total) as totalspent, c.firstname, c.lastname
      from invoices i left join
           customers c
           on c.customerid = i.customerid
      group by c.country, c.firstname, c.lastname
     )
select ic.*
from ic
where ic.totalspent = (select max(ic2.totalspent) from ic ic2 where ic2.country = ic.country);
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get the desired output, while at the same time keeping the query easy to ready and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no window functions.

This is just an approach, check if it is a solution for your scenario:

Let's suppose this is your current results:

```
sqlite> create table c ( i int, p varchar(100), c varchar(100));
sqlite> insert into c values
   ...> ( 100, 'pedro', 'USA'),
   ...> ( 120, 'marta', 'Spain'),
   ...> (  90, 'juan',  'USA' ),
   ...> ( 130, 'laura', 'Spain' );
```

Then, the query, may be:

```
sqlite> select c.*
   ...> from c inner join
   ...>  ( select c, max(i) as i from c group by c) m 
   ...> on c.c = m.c and c.i=m.i;
```

On subquery, we get the max value for each country.

Results:

```
100|pedro|USA
130|laura|Spain
```

**Notice** in your case you should to do the selects from your select.